# I want _scanQR() function is to e executed whenever my flutter app is opened before any UI setup

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode, flutter-layout

I am making barcode scanner application in flutter
Following _`scanQR()` function open the camera and scan the barcode and store result in qrResult String.
I want this function is to be executed whenever my application is opened without any button onPress event and after scanning the barcode the GUI should be setup.

```
 Future _scanQR() async {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function in the init state. Make sure you have stateful one

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scanQR();
  }
```